# Build artifact with provided dependency then choose and specify it from a command line

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath

I have 3 maven modules:

1. *core*
2. *data*
3. *data-dev*

*core* has a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

*data* and *data-dev* are consist of a single file: *test.txt*, located in *test.data* package in both modules. (Here is the first question: is it a good idea to build 2 artifacts with different names but with the same package structure in it?)

- *data.txt* inside *data* has a simple string "hello world".
- *data.txt* inside *data-dev* has a different string "hello dev".

*core* module loads data.txt like a resource and outputs string from file to the system.out like this:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("test/data/data.txt");
if (is == null) {
    System.out.println("No Resource");
    return;
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

My idea is to provide *data.jar* or *data-dev.jar* from a command line to run *core.jar* with one or another version of *data.txt* file.

But I can't find working solution.
What is a correct way to implement this idea and run jar file from a command line?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any value in providing static resources as a classpath dependency of a runnable jar in your case. Just pass the file name as a command line argument. So you either run it as:

```
java -jar core.jar -Ddata=data.txt
```

or as:

```
java -jar core.jar -Ddata=data-dev.txt
```

depending on the environment, and then do:

```
String filename = System.getProperty("data");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

If you really want this data to be packed into a jar file, then you could also unpack it at runtime with [java.util.jar API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html).